# How would I use regex to ignore multiple parenthesis inside a string?

Tags: c++, regex, data-extraction

Seems like every answer I have seen doesn't have a simple to read solution. Here is the input I am working with.

(input of strings)

> INSERT((AIRBUS,A340,295,137),PlaneType)
> INSERT((1050,Meal,N),Flight)
> INSERT((1050,10/5/2021,1/1/2021,19:20,1/1/2002,20:40,8.0),FlightLegInstance)
> INSERT((SEA,Seattle, WA),AirPort)

The goal is to use regex to capture the data inside the nested parenthesis.
For example:

> INSERT((AIRBUS,A340,295,137),PlaneType)

I need to grab

> "AIRBUS,A340,295,137"

I am currently using this to search for what I need

```
regex_search(input, regex("PlaneType")) //Example
```

but I am falling short in understanding how to extract the data inside, because once I have the data I will need to pass it off to a function etc etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

(update)
The best I have so far is:

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

Which results in this

> ((AIRBUS,A340,295,137)

So I am not sure how to remove the leading and trailing parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, the data will always be in that nested parenthesis.

Comment: [`R"([^()]*\(\(([^()]*)\),[^()]*\))"`](https://regex101.com/r/x5u9ws/1)?

Comment: I am definitely open to new ways to approach it. Ideas?

Comment: Thanks Austin, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since I try to avoid Regex when possible, here is an example of using `substr`:

```
std::size_t endPos = str.find("),"); //gets the end of the inner parentheses
std::string sub = str.substr(8, endPos - 8); //substrings to pull inner string out
```

I don't know how you are reading these strings in, but here is a full example to just dump out the provided samples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vs;

    std::string s1 = "INSERT((AIRBUS,A340,295,137), PlaneType)";
    std::string s2 = "INSERT((1050,Meal,N), Flight)";
    std::string s3 = "INSERT((1050,10/5/2021,1/1/2021,19:20,1/1/2002,20:40,8.0), FlightLegInstance)";
    std::string s4 = "INSERT((SEA,Seattle,WA), AirPort)";

    vs.push_back(s1);
    vs.push_back(s2);
    vs.push_back(s3);
    vs.push_back(s4);

    for (int i = 0; i < vs.size(); i++) {
        std::size_t endPos = vs[i].find("),");
        std::string sub = vs[i].substr(8, endPos - 8);
        std::cout << sub << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that seems a boat load easier to understand than the hieroglyphics that is regex. I appreciate that help man. Thanks!

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> vs{s1, s2, s3, s4};` might be used to avoid the `push_back`s.